# how to use the stored procs using petapoco

Tags: petapoco

I have created a stored procedure in data base.

```
 var db = new PetaPoco.Database("connection name");
            return db.Query<sppoco>("exec spstp");
```

I declared a `spppoco.cs` in models with the column names I used in stored procedure

```
 public class spppoco
    {
        public int rid { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int Address { get; set; }

    }
```

But when I am executing I am getting an error like Invalid object name 'sppoco'.

Answer (score 2):

That's easy! It's just a typo.

[image]